# Authentication with Sorcery and Google Authenticator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sorcery, google-authenticator

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to implement Google Authenticator with Sorcery? My Rails app currently makes use of Sorcery for authentication.

Secondly, is Devise more superior to Sorcery. If so, how/why? And is it easier implementing Google Authenticator with Devise?

Thanks.